# Mysqli connection always fails for php7

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

i was using mysql_connect & it was working without issue. updated to php7 as it is fast but unable to connect to database.

here is my code.

```
function sql_connect($host, $user, $password, $db, $creat_db = 0)

{
    $dbi=mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password,$db);

        if (!$dbi)

    die("cannot connect to mysql server");

        return $dbi;


}


 $conn=sql_connect($db_info['host'], $db_info['user'], $db_info['pass'], $db_info['dbname']);
```

sql query function is

```
function sql_query($query)
{

   global $dbtype,$conn,$config;

    if (!$res = mysqli_query($conn,$query)) {

        echo"SQL query error!<br><b>Error infomation:</b><hr>[SQL]<br>".htmlspecialchars($query)."<br><br>[Error]<br><font color=red>".mysqli_error($conn)."</font>";exit();
    }
    return $res;

}
```

here is simple query

```
  $res = sql_query("select * from `table1`");
```

but i always get this error SQL query error select * from `table1`
 i am not getting any error. whatever i am writing in failed query i am getting . my error display is on and i have added ini_set & E_All also

always output is

```
output is 

SQL query error!
Error infomation:
[SQL]
select * from `table1`

[Error]
```

any help will be great

Comment: What is the actual error you are getting?

Comment: Try echoing `mysqli_error($conn)` right after you execute your query

Comment: @MattRink that is the problem. i am not getting any error. whatever i am writing in failed query i am getting . my error display is on and i have added ini_set & E_All also

Comment: If you're not getting any error, _what is the problem?_

Comment: @Manav i am really fruestrated. tried all these several time then thought of taking some other guy advise.almost tried everything

Comment: Why do you feel the need to use functions though? Why not use the `mysqli_` interface directly? And while you're at it, might as well use the OOP interface.

Comment: @Manav output is SQL query error!
Error infomation:
[SQL]
select * from `table1`

[Error]

Comment: @Qirel you are right. i have checked through direct mysqli & it works but as i said its old site & probably 10000 calls are there with sql_query so if i can make it work i will avoid changing manually to all. is through function it will have any impact on speed ??

Comment: I understand. Do some basic debugging, what is `var_dump($conn)` inside the query-function? Does `mysqli_error($conn)` output anything? Well, you would have one additional function-call, but the difference in performance is negligible.

Comment: @Qirel this one i missed to try. very valid advise. i think i should get something.

Comment: @Qirel its blank. 0 byte

Comment: Huh, it should either say "null" or something, I don't get where you got the zero byte data from. Oh well, there's your issue! So either `$conn` isn't initialized before calling this function, or perhaps it's not in the global scope.

Comment: @Qirel checking,. will update. i dumped var in text file with file put contents

Comment: @Qirel i added connection variable directly in sql_query function call & when i dumped i got lot of data in top of page but no error & blank page.

Comment: @Qirel var_dump($res);
 gives NULL

Comment: `table1` exists in the database?

Comment: The biggest problem here with these largely useless wrapper functions is they wall off important functionality exposed by the `mysqli` adapter: Placeholder values. Without those you're at severe risk of having SQL injection bugs. Whenever possible use `mysqli` directly. If you'd like an abstraction layer, why not use [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/), [Propel](http://propelorm.org/) or
[Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent)?

Comment: @tadman thanks for ur input. we are thinking to move to direct